# Regular_expression python

Tags: python

I have a `file.txt` and I want to detect the first occurrence of `udp:data` that comes after the first occurrence of `Report`.

I have done this using another method but I like to use regular expressions in Python.

```
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.236896000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.238663000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.240578000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.242551000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.244473000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.246256000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.248466000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.250880000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
192.168.1.13    232.0.4.3   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.252270000 eth:ip:igmp Membership Report group 232.0.4.3
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.252680000 eth:ip:udp:data Source port: 49152  Destination port: aesop
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.254618000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.256553000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.258349000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.260234000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.262228000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.264001000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.265925000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.268151000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.270116000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.271854000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.273810000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.275996000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.278013000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.279936000 eth:ip:udp:data Source port: 49152  Destination port: aesop
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.281734000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.283952000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.285879000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.287654000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.289663000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.291609000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.293337000 eth:ip:udp:adp  
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.295284000 eth:ip:udp:adp
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Python code you have tried. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

That can easily be done using the standard shell tools [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), and [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head).

```
$ sed -n '/Report/,$p' so.txt | grep udp:data | head -1
193.253.155.253 232.0.4.2   Apr 20, 2016 17:17:04.252680000 eth:ip:udp:data Source port: 49152  Destination port: aesop
```